# Select by increasing order SQL

Tags: sql

Table:

```
  id | year |     score 
-----+------+-----------
  12 | 2011 |     0.929
  12 | 2014 |     0.933
  12 | 2010 |     0.937
  12 | 2013 |     0.938
  12 | 2009 |      0.97
  13 | 2010 |     0.851
  13 | 2014 |     0.881
  13 | 2011 |     0.885
  13 | 2013 |     0.895
  13 | 2009 |     0.955
  16 | 2009 |     0.867
  16 | 2011 |     0.881
  16 | 2012 |     0.886
  16 | 2013 |     0.897
  16 | 2014 |     0.953
```

Desired Output:

```
  id | year |     score 
-----+------+-----------
  16 | 2009 |     0.867
  16 | 2011 |     0.881
  16 | 2012 |     0.886
  16 | 2013 |     0.897
  16 | 2014 |     0.953
```

I'm having difficulties in trying to output scores that are increasing in respect to the year.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the goal to return all records from the highest value of the `id` column?

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: do you want only to return the highest score for each year?

Comment: My goal is to return the id with constantly increasing scores over the years.

Answer (score 7):

So you want to select `id` = 16 because it is the only one that has steadily increasing values.

Many versions of SQL support `lag()`, which can help solve this problem.  You can determine, for a given id, if all the values are increasing or decreasing by doing:

```
select id,
       (case when min(score - prev_score) < 0 then 'nonincreasing' else 'increasoing' end) as grp
from (select t.*, lag(score) over (partition by id order by year) as prev_score
      from table t
     ) t
group by id;
```

You can then select all "increasing" ids using a join:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (select id
      from (select t.*, lag(score) over (partition by id order by year) as prev_score
            from table t
           ) t
      group by id
      having min(score - prev_score) > 0
     ) inc
     on t.id = inc.id;
```

Comment: so this is for when same score counts as an 'increase'?  If a repeated score over the next sequential year wasn't supposed to return results, it would be `having min(score - prev_score) > 0`?

Comment: @Beth . . . In my experience, often when the word "increasing" is used, it really means "non-decreasing".  Similarly, "positive" often means "non-negative".  But, you are right, the question clearly saying increasing so I removed the `=`.